# Node JS pg Pool auto reconnect if Postgres service restart. Client reconnects but see multiple sessions. Normal start up only should see one

Tags: postgresql, pg

Code below works aside from when Postgres Server is down. After it comes back and socket is available see multiple connections. Normally on clean start of the js it shows only one connection, on a reconnect I'm seeing sometimes more than 5.
Any Ideas why?

```
var express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fs = require("fs-extra");

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const R = require('ramda');

require ('dotenv').config();
var reconnectLoop = 0;
var sleepInterval = 0;
var pg = require('pg');
const pool = {
user: process.env.DB_USER,
host: process.env.DB_SERVER,
database: process.env.DB_NAMESPACE,
password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
port: process.env.DB_PORT,
max: 1,
connectionTimeoutMillis: 2000
};


let date_ob = new Date();

// current date
// adjust 0 before single digit date
let date = ("0" + date_ob.getDate()).slice(-2);
// current month
let month = ("0" + (date_ob.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
// current year
let year = date_ob.getFullYear();
// current hours
let hours = date_ob.getHours();
// current minutes
let minutes = date_ob.getMinutes();
// current seconds
let seconds = date_ob.getSeconds();


let client;
const postgresDBConnect = () => {
    const startedAt = new Date().getTime();
    
    client = new pg.Client(pool)
    
    client.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log('startedAt:-', startedAt);
        console.log('crashedAt:-', new Date().getTime());
        
        //Reconnect
        reconnectLoop = reconnectLoop + 1;
        sleepInterval = reconnectLoop * 1000;
        console.log('Trying Reconnect1' + ' Sleep Timeout ' + sleepInterval);
        setTimeout(postgresDBConnect,sleepInterval);
                
    });


    client.connect(err => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Connection issue:', err.stack)
        reconnectLoop = reconnectLoop + 1
        sleepInterval = 1000 * reconnectLoop
        console.log('Trying Reconnect2' + '. Sleep Timeout ' + sleepInterval)
        setTimeout(postgresDBConnect,sleepInterval)
        
    } else {
        console.log('Connected to Postgres Server') 
    }
    });

};

console.log('Starting UP Postgres Connection');
postgresDBConnect();

var user = {}
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/post-test', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Got body:', req.body);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.post('/insertactivity', function (req, res) {
        console.log('InsertActivity, Got body:', req.body);
        res.sendStatus(200);
    var string = JSON.stringify(req.body);
        var objectValue = JSON.parse(string);
       
        console.log('currenttime:',objectValue["domain_activity"]["currenttime"]);
        console.log('username:',objectValue["domain_activity"]["username"]);
        console.log('domain:',objectValue["domain_activity"]["domain"]);
        console.log('computer:',objectValue["domain_activity"]["computer"]);
        console.log('ipaddr:',objectValue["domain_activity"]["ipaddr"]);
        console.log('action:',objectValue["domain_activity"]["action"]);
        console.log('macaddr:',objectValue["domain_activity"]["macaddr"]);
        console.log('uuid:',objectValue["domain_activity"]["uuid"]);

objdata1 = objectValue["domain_activity"]["currenttime"];
objdata2 = objectValue["domain_activity"]["username"];
objdata3 = objectValue["domain_activity"]["domain"];
objdata4 = objectValue["domain_activity"]["computer"];
objdata5 = objectValue["domain_activity"]["ipaddr"];
objdata6 = objectValue["domain_activity"]["action"];
objdata7 = objectValue["domain_activity"]["macaddr"];
objdata8 = objectValue["domain_activity"]["uuid"];

client.query(`insert into public.authentication_activity (currenttime,username,domain,computer,ipaddr,action,macaddr,uuid) values (
'${objdata1}',
'${objdata2}',
'${objdata3}',
'${objdata4}',
'${objdata5}',
'${objdata6}',
'${objdata7}',
'${objdata8}')`).then(res => {

    }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err.stack);
        })
//.finally(() => {
   // client.end()
});

app.post('/updateactivity', function (req, res) {
        console.log('UpdateActivity, Got body:', req.body);             
    res.sendStatus(200);
        var string = JSON.stringify(req.body);
        var objectValue = JSON.parse(string);
        console.log('username:',objectValue["domain_activity"]["username"]);
        console.log('uuid:',objectValue["domain_activity"]["uuid"]);

objdata9 = objectValue["domain_activity"]["username"];
objdata10 = objectValue["domain_activity"]["uuid"];

client.query(`select public.sessionduration ('${objdata9}','${objdata10}')`).then(res => {
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err.stack);
        })
//.finally(() => {
   // client.end()
});


var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port
   console.log("Server.js app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})


// prints date & time in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format
```

console.log(date + "/" + month + "/" + year + " " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by adding client.end()
Now only see one connection is postgres is restarted

```
client.connect(err => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Connection issue:', err.stack)
        reconnectLoop = reconnectLoop + 1
        sleepInterval = 1000 * reconnectLoop
        console.log('Trying Reconnect2' + '. Sleep Timeout ' + sleepInterval)
        client.end()
        setTimeout(postgresDBConnect,sleepInterval)
        
    } else {
        console.log('Connected to Postgres Server') 
    }
    });
```